# Check for empty field after encryption

Tags: javascript, php, encryption

I have this piece of html code:

```
<form action="register.php" method="post">
       Email: <input type="text" name="email" /><br />
       Username: <input type="text" name="username" /><br />
       Password: <input type="password" name="p" id="password" /><br />
       <input type="button" value="Register" onclick="formhash(this.form, this.form.password);" />
</form>
```

Once the register button is pressed, an encryption gets called and the password gets encrypted immediately. I thought this would be a very good and secure way to do it, however I can't seem to check if the passworld field named "p" is empty or not because if the user leaves the field empty when registering, the encryption encrypts the empty field, hence it's not empty anymore. I need a way to check if the user leaves the "p" field empty or not, because it shouldn't be possible to make a password with 0 characters.

I know this problem can be solved by javascript, but I need a secure way to check if the field is empty or not, therefore I'd like to get a PHP solution.

The register.php:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="sha512.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="forms.js"></script>

<?php
include 'db_connect.php';

//Just to check that the p field is encrypted already at this point. 
echo $_POST['p'];

// The username
$username = $_POST['username'];
// The email
$email = $_POST['email'];
// The hashed password from the form
$password = $_POST['p']; 
// Create a random salt
$random_salt = hash('sha512', uniqid(mt_rand(1, mt_getrandmax()), true));
// Create salted password (Careful not to over season)
$password = hash('sha512', $password.$random_salt);

// Add your insert to database script here. 
// Make sure you use prepared statements!
if ($insert_stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO members (username, email, password, salt) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)")) {    
   $insert_stmt->bind_param('ssss', $username, $email, $password, $random_salt); 
   // Execute the prepared query.
   $insert_stmt->execute();
}
?>
```

Comment: You mean: if (0 === strlen($_POST['p'])) { /* password is empty */ }

Comment: Can I add that line in my register.php page? Wont the $_POST['p'] be encrypted already and therefore not empty?

Comment: You should also use this to hash passwords: password_hash($password, PASSWORD_BCRYPT); It will add a salt automagically, and there is password_verify($password, $passwordFromDb) to verify it.

Comment: "Once the register button is pressed, an encryption gets called" Does that happen on the client side? Cause if so then your script is not secure.

Comment: Anything on the client side is exposed and can get reverse engineered.

Comment: @Sébastien, it happens both on client and serverside, the password is encrypted with sha512 using JS, and it is assigned the values with a hash and salt in PHP as you can see on the register.php page. mhmmh hope you can understand me.

Comment: do AJAX POST call to your PHP script, check it `if(!isset($_POST['0']) || empty($_POST['p'])){ echo "empty"; }`

Comment: If you can post the unencrypted password to check its length in PHP, then your app is not secure. If you do the encryption client-side then you can check for the unencrypted password's length client-side in JS as well.

Comment: @Sébastien, I can't check the length in PHP because the password variable gets encrypted right away. I am still not sure if the encryption is client-side or not actually. The JS files themself are client-side but the password gets encrypted server-side I guess?

Comment: When you hash the password client-side then the hash becomes just as insecure as the plaintext password and you're *STILL* transmitting it in plain text. ***Use HTTPS and drop the client-side shenanigans.***

Comment: If anyone monitor your traffic they can still get that password. It's just changed from the original string to the hash. It is not a security feature!

Answer (score 3):

If anyone monitor your traffic they can still get that password. It's just changed from the original string to the hash. It is not a security feature!

If you are worried about someone intercepting the data, use https.

Remove your client side hash:

```
<form action="register.php" method="post">
       Email: <input type="text" name="email" /><br />
       Username: <input type="text" name="username" /><br />
       Password: <input type="password" name="p" id="password" /><br />
       <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Register" />
</form>
```

Note: password_hash is new in PHP 5.5, if your version is older try this [userland implementation](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat).

Change your PHP code to this:

```
<?php
include 'db_connect.php';

if (!isset($_POST['p']) || (10 > strlen($_POST['p']))) {
    //password too short!
}

if (!isset($_POST['username']) || (3 > strlen($_POST['username']))) {
    //username too short!
}

// The username
$username = $_POST['username'];
// The email
$email = $_POST['email']
if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
    //not a valid email (mostly)
}
// The unaltered password from the form
$password = $_POST['p']; 

// Create salted password (Careful not to over season)
$password = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_BCRYPT);

// Add your insert to database script here. 
// Make sure you use prepared statements!
if ($insert_stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO members (username, email, password) VALUES (?, ?, ?)")) {    
   $insert_stmt->bind_param('sss', $username, $email, $password); 
   // Execute the prepared query.
   $insert_stmt->execute();
}
```

Use this to verify the password on login/auth:

```
password_verify($password, $passwordFromDb)
```

Comment: This, but with HTTPS if you're actually worried about someone intercepting the password.

Comment: I will try implementing this instead, I hope I can still use the same log in function. I might need a lot time to try all these new ideas out, so I am afraid I can't come with any response too soon. Thank you :-)

Comment: Hmm, when I implement this code, nothing happens when I press the button, am I supposed to make it submit and do it that way? Or exactly as the code does it? Because that doesn't work somehow?

Comment: @user2826397 Use `<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Register" />` instead. `type="button"` is not the best option.

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_IF in /home/virtual/url.com/public_html/moreurl/register.php on line 16 (Line 16 is the if "(!filter_var($email, FILTER_EMAIL)) {") line. Hmm, I don't really know what the problem is.

Comment: Nevermind, you forgot a ";". Though I faced this problem:
Warning: filter_var() expects parameter 2 to be long, string given in /home/virtual/url/public_html/moreurl/register.php on line 18 Fatal error: Call to undefined function password_hash() in /home/virtual/url/public_html/moreurl/register.php on line 25

Comment: @user2826397 Added a link to userland implementation of password_hash for older PHP versions.

Comment: @user2826397 Changed filter constant and input type for submit.

Comment: But I think my PHP version is 5.5+ ? Is there any way to check it, and if it isn't I am going to get it!

Comment: Ah I see, everything works now. I am going to get PHP 5.5 before I move further with this in order to make this 100 % good and not something half-hearted. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

have a javascript function that validates the form when the register button is clicked:

use this to check if the password field has any input:

```
if (document.getElementById('Password').value.length!=0) {
   //encrypt and submit form
} else {
   //return to form and display error to user
}
```

side note, always use SSL to submit passwords, forcing the user to hash their password before sending and then hashing it again could be excessive and won't prevent anyone from reusing the password or hash in an attack.

Comment: Seriously do not use client side "encryption". Do not hash the password multiple times

Comment: Yeah, that does seem a bit excessive.  Added a note to my answer regarding that.

Comment: Hashing the password client-side just make the hash the password. Anyone intercepting the hash can still use it in a replay attack.

Comment: @Sammitch that's why I said: "always use SSL to submit passwords"